Shade tail in ggplot stat_density()
I've produced a density plot in ggplot, and would now like to shade the tail of the distribution north of the 95th percentile. This achieves what I want:
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars |> 
  ggplot(aes(disp)) + 
  geom_density() +
  geom_density(aes(x = disp, 
                   y = if_else(x > quantile(mtcars$disp, 0.95), 
               after_stat(density), NA)), 
               fill = "grey", alpha = 0.5)


This does require, however, that I reference the original data again. Is there a way to replace mtcars$disp in the aes() with a reference to the data being passed to ggplot()?
Ideally a solution would flexibly accommodate splitting the data. My solution above obviously fails with facets/fills/colors unless I pre-compute the quantiles within each group:
mtcars |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c(mpg, qsec)) |> 
    ggplot(aes(value)) +
      geom_density() +
      geom_density(???) +
      facet_wrap(~ name)


library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>% { 
  ggplot(., aes(disp)) + 
  geom_density() +
  geom_density(aes(x = disp, 
                   y = if_else(x > quantile(.$disp, 0.95), 
                               after_stat(density), NA)), 
               fill = "grey", alpha = 0.5) }

or using |>:
mtcars |> 
  list(mydata = _) |>
  with(ggplot(mydata, aes(disp)) + 
         geom_density() +
         geom_density(aes(x = disp, 
                          y = if_else(x > quantile(mydata[["disp"]], 0.95), 
                                      after_stat(density), NA)), 
                      fill = "grey", alpha = 0.5))


Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.0.2

Any way to do this without the magrittr pipe? This solution falls apart as soon as there is more than one set of data in the plot, e.g. if one splits on color, fill, etc.

@RoyalTS see the updates.

And btw, would you post an example of this not working out so I can make sure my updates addressed the issues?

Just posted an edit

@RoyalTS I'd argue that is a totally different question somewhat unrelated to the use of base or magrittr pipe and referencing the data.

A possible option with stat_density_ridges:
library(ggridges)
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |>
  pivot_longer(c(disp, mpg, qsec)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(value, name, fill = factor(stat(quantile)))) +
  stat_density_ridges(
    geom = "density_ridges_gradient",
    calc_ecdf = TRUE,
    quantiles = 0.95
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(name = "Percentile", labels = c("<95", ">95")) +
  theme_ridges()


Created on 2024-04-13 with reprex v2.1.0
